# CSS not interpreted when in the style property of a tag

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

My problem is when I put **inline CSS** in a tag like this:

```
<div style='border : 1.5px solid black; color:red;'>...</div>
```

> This is just an example not the one which causing the issue.

The second property, here `color: red;`, is not interpreted when I use it in a **PHP** variable to generate a pdf later with *HTML2PDF*.

```
$content2 = "<html>
                <head>
                       ...
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h3 style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>".$design."</h3>
                        <div style='margin: 15px;'>&nbsp;<strong>".$taille."</strong>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<i>".$scient."</i><br /></div>
                        <div style='border : 1.5px solid black; width:100px;'><img src='".$chemin."' style='width: 100px;' /></div><p style='margin-top : -75px; margin-right : -250px;'>origine :".$origine."</p>

                </body>
            </html>
 ";
```

Please help me into this.

Comment: Should be - `color:red;`.

Comment: @Kentin why are you using single colon ` ' ` ? you can go for like this

`$content2 = '<h3 style="margin-bottom: 0px;">'.$design.'</h3>'` and you're good to go, I've done the same in my HTML2PDF

Comment: I tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS uses colons to define values. You seem to be using the equals sign multiple times to define values.

Comment: i define all my values with colons; check the code, i don't see your point

Comment: You use `width=100px;` when you define CSS. Same thing in the first code exterpt, you use `color=red;` when you should be using `color:red;`

Comment: Yes because the first code was just an example i don't actually use it, i edited it

Answer (score 0):

Change this **color:red;** `<div style='border : 1.5px solid black; color:red;'>...</div>`

Comment: First line is just an example, the real problem is on <p style='margin-top : -75px; margin-right : -250px;'>